# Return values from Process.start

Tags: c#, vb.net, shellexecute, process.start

`Shellexecute` returns a value greater than 32 if it is success. If the function fails, it returns an error value that indicates the cause of the failure. But in case of Process.start i didn't get any option of this kind. I tried using `Process.ExitCode` but it will return value only after process gets closed. But i want to check whether process gets started successfully. Also what is equivalent of shellexecute return value in process.start?

Comment: Process.Start returns boolean true if it started ok, see MSDN link here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> But i want to check whether process gets started successfully

From the documentation for [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The return value true indicates that a new process resource was started. If the process resource specified by the FileName member of the StartInfo property is already running on the computer, no additional process resource is started. Instead, the running process resource is reused and false is returned.

That boolean value does not indicate that an error occurred, only that the process is already running.

If a true error occurs, i.e., an exception, then you can catch the [Win32Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.win32exception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use the [NativeErrorCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.win32exception.nativeerrorcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to get the error code you are after.

Only two other exceptions may be thrown; an InvalidOperationException or an ObjectDisposedException.  Neither of those require an error code to diagnose the cause of the problem.